# What is idm_frm attribute within html?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, iframe, frame

I'm seeing an HTML attribute and I want to know more about it

I looked for answers in StackOverflow

```
<iframe src="NIB_MainFrame.asp" name="Principal" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:0;padding:0;border:0;margin:0;display:block;overflow-y:hidden" __idm_frm__="467"></iframe>`
```

I'm talking about the **idm_frm** attribute, sometimes I see it with the context of Selenium and I also saw **idm_id**

Any idea what it is?

Comment: It's not a standard attribute, however it is probably added by JavaScript, or in the very least used by JavaScript.

Comment: I'm really trying to find any documentation for what this means but can't seem to find.

Comment: You probably won't find documentation on it, since it is a non standard HTML attribute and is likely used by a proprietary JavaScript library.

Comment: I think it is created automatically by Selenium

Answer (score 3):

you are a windows user and you have IDM browser extension installed. IDM  extension adds unique id's to identify downloadable content. that's all

Answer (score 0):

To start with [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) itself doesn't add any **tag** or **attribute** within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

By all possible means the attribute **`__idm_frm__="467"`** within the HTML, which is as follows:

```
<iframe src="NIB_MainFrame.asp" name="Principal" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:0;padding:0;border:0;margin:0;display:block;overflow-y:hidden" __idm_frm__="467"></iframe>`
```

looks to be dynamic and the *attribute* seems to be created/added by a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) or [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

As per the HTML in the question [C#: Selenium - Element is not a frame element : FRAMESET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658631/c-selenium-element-is-not-a-frame-element-frameset) it becomes much more clearer that the *attribute* is dynamically generated.

```
<iframe src="NIB_MainFrame.asp" name="Principal" style="height:100%;width:100%;border:0;padding:0;border:0;margin:0;display:block;overflow-y:hidden" __idm_frm__="467"></iframe>
<frameset id="frmSet" rows="55,0,*,24" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="no">
    <frame noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" name="Header" src="NIB_Header.asp" __idm_frm__="472">
    <frame noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" name="Menu" src="Blank.htm" __idm_frm__="473">
    <frame noresize="noresize" scrolling="auto" name="Corpo" src="NIB_Pre_Bridge.asp?txtAgencia=4346&amp;txtConta=014543708" __idm_frm__="474">
    <frame noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" name="Rodape" src="NIB_Rodape.asp" __idm_frm__="475">
</frameset>
</iframe>
```

An [example](https://github.com/Trapsta/jhq/blob/master/linkedin.html#L1554) of [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) enabled [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) containing the `__idm_frm__` attribute:

```
<section id="ember22904" class="ad-banner-container ember-view"><iframe class="ad-banner" width="496" height="80" src="about:blank" scrolling="no" title="advertisement" kwframeid="3" __idm_frm__="1347"></iframe>
```

An [example](https://codepen.io/96naveen/pen/myxvpO.html) of implementation in *Facebook* containing the `__idm_frm__` attribute::

```
<iframe style="display: none;" __idm_frm__="21" id="IFRAME_1007"></iframe>
```

---

### Conclusion

As the *attribute* **`__idm_frm__="xyz"`** does not contains a static value and dynamic in nature a wise decission would be to not to include this attribute while constructing any of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890).

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)